# Issues understanding this java recursive backtracking example

Tags: java, recursion

The problem is as follows:

You have an array of integers, such as [2,3,1,4,0]. You want to find a path to the last index. You can either move left or right, starting from index 0. The amount of steps you can move along the array depends on the value at the index position. In the end you want to print all the paths.

In my example, you start at index 0, which contains 2. You cannot move left, therefore you move right. Now you are at index 2, which contains 1. You can then move left 1 to reach index 1 which contains 3, then move right 3 to reach the last index.

I am having issues with both the implementation and an idea of how to print out all possible solutions.

My code is as follows:

```
public static boolean solveH(int index){
    if(index == data.size()-1){
        printSol(stages);
        return true;
    }
    boolean success = false;
    if(!success && (index + Integer.parseInt(data.get(index)) < data.size())){
        String temp = data.get(index);
        data.set(index, temp + "R");
        stages.add(copy(data));
        data.set(index, temp);
        success = solveH(index + Integer.parseInt(data.get(index)));
        stages.remove(stages.size()-1);
    }
    if(!success && (index - Integer.parseInt(data.get(index)) > 0)){
        String temp = data.get(index);
        data.set(index, temp + "L");
        stages.add(copy(data));
        data.set(index, temp);
        success = solveH(index - Integer.parseInt(data.get(index)));
        stages.remove(stages.size()-1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So we have no context class, no data, no main. printSol doesn't look like a standardlib Java method. Or stages - what is it, where does it come from? Not from the method arguments, so it is a static variable - right? Why do I have to puzzle this out? Create a [mcve], please.

Comment: In Line 6 you set success to false. In Line 7 you test success - what might have happened in between? At the start of the next block, you test again. But you wanted not only to find the first, but all solutions, so even if you found one R, you should search in L.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be: At every field visit left, visit right (in fact - branch at every step).

Ok - first, like you did: look if we reached the target.

Then, save the value at that index for stepping left and right and then set the value to 0 as mark for 'visited'. You're anyhow frozen on a zero field and the check for reaching the target is based on the index = last index.

Instead of strings and parsing, just store plain numbers in an array.

Code:

```
public class StepArray  {
    // using static fields/methods is a bit ugly. Maybe improve main,
    // to allow passing an array to visit dynamically. 
    static int[] data = new int [] {2, 3, 1, 4, 0};
    static int len = data.length;

    public static boolean solveH (int index){
        if (index == len - 1) {
            System.out.println ("found at index " + index + "!");
            return true;
        }
        // save the value before overwriting:
        int step = data[index];
        // already visited? 
        if (step == 0) return false;
        // mark for later visitors as visited by setting to 0:
        data[index] = 0;

        if (index + step < len) {
            System.out.print (" R:" + step);
            solveH (index + step);
        }
        // no need to visit 0 again, which is always the starting point
        if (index - step > 0) {
            System.out.print (" L:" + step);
            solveH (index - step);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
            solveH (0);
    }
}
```

Here is the improved version for more fun and flexibility (the core algorithm only has cosmetic changes):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ArraySteps  {

    int[] data;
    int len;

    public ArraySteps (int [] values) {
        data = values;
        len = data.length;
        solveH (0);
        System.out.println ();
    }

    boolean solveH (int index) {
        if (index == len - 1) {
            System.out.println (" found at index " + index + "!");
            return true;
        }
        int step = data[index];
        // already visited
        if (step == 0) return false;
        // mark for later visitors as visited by setting to 0:
        data[index] = 0;

        boolean r = false, l = false;

        if (index + step < len) {
            System.out.print (" R:" + step);
            r = solveH (index + step);
        }
        if (index - step > 0) {
            System.out.print (" L:" + step);
            l = solveH (index - step);
        }
        if (r || l) return true;
        System.out.println (" dead end.");
        return false;
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        // default, no args:
        int [] param;
        System.out.println ("args.length: " + args.length);
        if (args.length == 0)
        {
             System.out.println ("default: ");
             param = new int [] {2, 3, 1, 4, 0};
        }
        // one arg: Generate count N random values
        else if (args.length == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Random: ");
            int anz = Integer.parseInt (args[0]);
            Random r = new Random ();
            param = new int [anz];
            for (int i = 0; i < anz - 1; ++i) {
                param [i] = r.nextInt (Math.min (anz/2, 9)) + 1;
            }
            param[anz-1] = 0;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println ("User defined: ");
            param = new int [args.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i)
            {
                param[i] = Integer.parseInt (args[i]);
            }
            param [args.length] = 0;
        }
        show (param);
        new ArraySteps (param);
    }

    private static void show (int[] ls)
    {
            for (int i: ls)
                    System.out.print (i + " ");
            System.out.println ();
    }
}
```